# How can i deploy a smart contract with Multiple files

Tags: blockchain, contract-deployment, bsc, compiler, binance

I am kinda new to this space. I just deployed my first smart contract to the BSC using Remix IDE. Now I used the very simple contract templates most online tutorials have always used. It is just a single-page file with a few lines of code in it. Just when I was beginning to think I'm done learning how to deploy contracts, I came across these multiple files (1 to 16 ) in number, all of them representing a single contact.

https://github.com/ChubbyDogeToken/ChubbyDoge

My question is how do I deploy the contract in the link above to BSC since it has multiple files. Do I deploy all 16 files separately, one after the other or is there a way all 16 files get deployed at once?

Secondly, if the only way is to deploy them one after the other, must they be deployed in a specific order, as in, 1 before the other? Will deploying them in a random order of 1 to 16 have any effect?

Comment: Take a look at [multisol](https://github.com/paulrberg/multisol/issues), might be helpful here.

Answer (score 0):

- Assuming the main contract is CDOGE, compiling all the 16 files, one by one, in the order of dependency (you should compile prerequisite files first and continue the job, until you finish with the CDOGE) and then deploying the CDOGE bytecode/abi would be enough to do the job. The final CDOGE has all the prerequisites inside. Check [this](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/93706/do-contracts-deploy-their-imported-dependency-contracts-or-do-they-point-to-liv) out. Test it with multiple simple contracts which are dependent to each other to examine it.
- In case you are interested in deploying all the 16 files, please see [1](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/45159/deploy-multiple-contracts-using-truffle), [2](https://medium.com/blockcentric/how-to-deploy-multiple-smart-contracts-using-truffle-5a7188a24366).

Hope this helps.